# Islamic view on self-harm

Tags: quran, allah, suicide

I am in a really troubled state of mind right now. Things are not going right in my life. I know that it is haram to harm oneself, but the thought of slitting myself on my wrists, forearms, neck, thighs, legs, torso and other parts is coming to my mind nowadays. Please suggest any dua or hadith or anything to improve my condition. And please make dua for me, it's a sincere request to everyone here. If there is any dua, hadith, ayah from the Noble Qur'an to help me calm down and bring peace to my heart, then please please, for the love of Allah SWT, suggest it to me. And please, as a final request, do not use rough language in the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, committing suicide will be punished in the same way on the Day of Resurrection as well as in Hellfire. Because in **Surah An-Nisa Verse 29**, Allah says: "**O you who have believed, [...]  And do not kill yourselves [or one another]. Indeed, Allah is to you ever Merciful.**"

The ahadith clearly state:

> The Prophet (ﷺ) said: [...] "*and whoever commits suicide with something, will be punished with the same thing in the (Hell) Fire.*" Al-Bukhari ([6652](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:6652))

> The Prophet (ﷺ) said: "*A man was inflicted with wounds and he committed suicide, and so Allah said*: "**My slave has caused death on himself hurriedly, so I forbid Paradise for him**." Al-Bukhari ([1363/4](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:1363))

> The Prophet (ﷺ) said: "*And if somebody commits suicide with anything in this world, he will be tortured with that very thing on the Day of Resurrection.*" Al-Bukhari ([6047](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:6047))

Make sure to calm yourself and consider the following (without answering it here, but by asking yourself): Do you pray 5 times a day (consistently)? Do you pray at all? Do you conduct the Dhikr after every prayer, specifically in the morning, afternoon, on Maghrib and before going to bed at night (which will give you strength, vitality and joy)? Do you abstain from haram? Do you think your character and your behaviour are according to the Sunnah? Do you edcuate yourself about Islam, so that you can avoid the bid'ah (innovation) and so that you can protect yourself from Shaytan (who wants you to harm yourself), from the people who want to harm or abuse you, from the Fitan of the Dunya and from the every evil that can negatively influence you?

If you answer these questions honestly (to yourself) and if you start changing your life today according to what I asked and according to what Islam offers you, then you will surely defeat your current state with the help of Allah, and you will enjoy this world and the reward that is promised for the Akhira.

Here are some Adhkar or Ad'iya for a distressful situation, which you can tackle with by saying these with full Yaqin (certainty) that Allah will help you:

- If a matter is very difficult for you:

> The Prophet (ﷺ) said: “*O Allah, nothing is easy but that which You make easy and You can make hardship easy if You will.* (اللَّهُمَّ لَا سَهْلَ إِلَّا مَا جَعَلْتَهُ سَهْلًا، وَأَنْتَ تَجْعَلُ الْحَزْنَ سَهْلًا إِذَا شِئْتَ - Allahumma la sahla illa ma ja'altahu sahla, wa anta taj'alul-hazna ila shi'ta sahla) Ibn as-Sunni (351) graded Sahih by Amir al-Muminin fil Hadith Ibn Hajar Asqalani

> The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said: "*May I not teach you phrases which you utter in distress:* '*Allah, Allah is my Lord, I do not associate anything as partner with Him.'*" (Allah - Allahu Rabbi la u-shriku bihi shay-a) Abu Dawud ([1525](https://sunnah.com/abudawud:1525)) graded Sahih by Sheikh Albani

> Anas bin Malik said: “***Whenever a matter would distress him, the Prophet (ﷺ) would say***": "*O Living, O Self-Sustaining Sustainer! In Your Mercy do I seek relief*" (Ya Hayyu Ya Qayyum, bi-Rahmatika astaghrith) At-Tirmidhi ([3524](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi:3524))

> The Prophet (ﷺ) said to his companions: "*Shall I not tell you some words which, if distress or grief befalls any of you and he offers this (supplication), it will bring him joy? It is the [Du'a of Dhu’l-Nun](https://quran.com/21:87?store=false&translations=85,207,131,206) (i.e. Yunus or Jonah)*: "*There is no god but You, Glory to You - Verily, I was one of the wrongdoers.*" (La ilaha illa anta Subhanak(a), inni kuntu minaz-zalimin) Sahih al-Jami' ([2605](https://shamela.ws/book/10757/446#p1))

<sup>I would recommend to you to talk to everyone that is reliable, especially to your family of course, and to consult an Islamic Psychotherapist who is conducting his profession according to Quran and Sunnah. You should never be ashamed to seek help, rather see it as a moment of strength by deciding to take this path for a new chance to get back stronger than ever; and Allah is capabale of all things to help you in your worst moments!</sup>

Comment: Jazakh Allah Khayr Akhi

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have to understand that self harm is a sin, and suicide is a one way ticket to jahannam, that is the truth.

I would suggest to you one thing, to put all of your trust in Allah, you should trust that Allah will help you in the darkest of times and you should just pray to Allah and be patient, one great thing to remember during hard times is that Allah will never put you through a burden that you cannot bear.